# OpenTok Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, opentok

I'm evaluating OpenTok for a text and video chat app.

The Xamarin.OpenTok.iOS library works for the video chat, but I have an issuee with the text functionality.
I'm trying to send a message from an iPhone to another.
For sending messages from the first iphone I use:

```
Session.SignalWithType("signal", message, Session.Connection,true, out err);
```

I don't receive the event ReceivedSignalType on the second iphone connected to the same session.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I used

```
Session.SignalWithType("chat", message, null, out err);
```